# Replace nested list index values with actual values

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I have 2 lists and 1 is a nested list

```
list1 = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]]
list2 = ['a','b','c']
```

I want to replace the nested list index values with the actual values such that the output looks like below

**Expected Output**

```
[['a','b'],['a','c'],['b','c']]
```

Comment: Just to rule out the XY problem: How do you get list1? If you generate it, maybe you could instead directly generate the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
res = [[list2[ei] for ei in e] for e in list1]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```

Answer (score 0):

An other approach

```
d = [[0,1],[0,2],[1,2]]
l = ['a','b','c']
r = [[l[i],l[j]] for i,j in d]
print(r)
#[['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']]
```